# Spring Boot application can't resolve the org.springframework.boot package

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I have set up a spring boot project using the [Spring Initializer](http://start.spring.io), I tried several times to create a new project or play with the dependencies, everything seems to be in place.

I am using STS(Spring Tool Suite) and it shows errors about the imports from the`org.springframework.boot` package. Running the application throws an exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation
>   problem:      SpringApplication cannot be resolved.

com.example.DemoApplication:

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.7.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <start-class>com.example.DemoApplication</start-class>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

I am using Java 1.8 with STS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [@SpringBootApplication cannot be resolved to a type In STS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41668819/springbootapplication-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-type-in-sts)

Answer (score 39):

change the version of spring boot parent

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
 </parent>
```

Comment: I spent 2 hours on this. YOu made my day.

Comment: It might be useful to precise that you need to set the latest version of Spring Boot. This is stupid, but I had to check the version of Spring Boot in the question just to be sure that it was about updating the version and not an issue with a specific version of SB, because the answer doesn't explain what's wrong...

Comment: Good solution but the reason?

Comment: @Chalpat , Follow [official spring boot guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/).

Comment: Changing to spring boot version 2.7.3 fixed my issue.

Answer (score 29):

Right button on project -> Maven -> Update Project

then check "Force update of Snapshots/Releases"

Comment: In my case, it was the root cause

Answer (score 9):

If the below step not work:

Replaced my Spring Boot 1.4.2.RELEASE to 1.5.10.RELEASE

- Right click on project and -> Maven-> Download Resources
- right click on project -> Maven-> Update project

The reason for this error might be multiple version of the same is downloaded into your maven local repository folder.

So follow below steps to clear all existing repository jars and download all from beginning based on dependencies defined in your POM.xml..

1. Go to build path . Check Maven Repository in the libraries added section.
2. Choose any jar and mousehover .. it will show the local repository location.
   generally it is : user/.m2/repository/....
3. Go to the location . and remove the repository folder contains.
4. Now right click on your project .. do Maven --> maven update. 
   This will solve your dependencies problem . as Maven will try to download all the items again from repository and build the project.

Answer (score 6):

Try this, It might work for you too.

1. Open command prompt and go to the project folder.
2. Build project (For Maven, Run **mvn clean install** and For Gradle, Run **gradle clean build**)
3. After successful build,

   - Open your project on any IDE (intellij / eclipse).
   - Restart your IDE incase it is already opened.

This worked for me on both v2.1 and v2.4

Answer (score 4):

From your pom.xml, try to remove spring repository entries, per default will download from maven repository. I have tried with 1.5.6.RELEASE and worked very well.

Answer (score 3):

In my project, updated the dependency on spring-boot-starter-parent from 2.0.0.release to 2.0.5.relese.
Doing this resolved the issue The import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication cannot be resolved

Answer (score 2):

Solution is change the version of Spring in file pom.xml

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you run your application as an jar, your `Manifest.MF` file should know which class has the main method.

To add this information when SpringBoot compiles your code, add `start-class` property on your pom file.

E.g.:

```
<properties>
        <start-class>com.example.DemoApplication</start-class>
</properties>
```

Comment: This seems to fix one of my problems, great. But now it still can't resolve the SpringApplication class and the annotation.

Comment: I had this problem before and I tried three differents things so I'm not quite sure which one fixed the problem:

1 - Update your Maven Project with force update or snapshots/release 2 - Restart your Spring Tool Suite
3 - Run Maven clean command.

Hope this helps.

Comment: If there is a single class containing a main you don't need it as it will be auto detected. Make sure the project is added as a maven project and not that you have imported it as a normal java project.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when I was trying to work with a basic spring boot app. I tried to use the latest spring-boot version from the official [spring-boot site](https://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/).

As on today, the latest version is **1.5.4.RELEASE**. But I keep getting compilation issues on my eclipse IDE irrespective of multiple cleanups to the project. I lowered the version of spring-boot to **1.5.3.RELEASE** and it simply *worked* !! Some of my earlier projects were using the old version which drove me to try this option.

Answer (score 1):

**I have encountered the same problem while my first Spring boot application.**

In tutorial i could see following dependency to start sample application

- Spring Boot 1.4.2.RELEASE
- Maven 3
- java 8

I have done the same, my Spring STS is recognizing all class but when i am annotating my main class with @SpringBootApplication it's not recognizing this class whereas i could see jar was available in the class path.

**I have following to resolve issues**

- Replaced my Spring Boot 1.4.2.RELEASE  to 1.5.3.RELEASE
- Right click on project and -> Maven-> Download Resources
- right click on project -> Maven-> Update project

After that it worked.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Mine worked by adding

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

instead of directly using other main dependencies, I have no idea why.

Answer (score 1):

After upgrading Spring boot to the latest version - 2.3.3.RELEASE. I also got this error - `Cannot resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:unknown`. Maven clean install, updating maven project, cleaning cache do not help.
The solution was adding version placeholder from spring boot parent pom:

```
 <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
   <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
   <scope>test</scope>
 </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

For me it was solved after removed the word `.RELEASE`

```
<version>2.5.3</version>
```

instead of

```
<version>2.5.3.RELEASE</version>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a problem with the JAR files in the local Maven repository. Try deleting the .m2/repository folder and hit Maven -> Update Project... another time to trigger Maven to download the dependencies again. I tried it and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessary to remove relative path. Just change the version parent of springframework boot. The following version 2.1.2 works successfully.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.appsdeveloperblog.app.ws</groupId>
    <artifactId>mobile-app-ws</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>mobile-app-ws</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.appsdeveloperblog.app.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>mobile-app-ws</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer may be out of topic for most of readers. In my case the dependency didn't update and "mvn clean" didn't work since my wifi network at the office is highly securised, leaving a "connection timed out". (same respect github pushes and pulls don't work)
I just moved to teathering with my phone and it works. 
Stupid, out of topic for most, but it may help some very specific cases.

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem when using STS. After edited something, I see that, some workspaces
 when create a project will happen this problem, and others will not. So I just create a new project in workspaces will not happen.

Answer (score 0):

add **${project.parent.version}** in build - plugin section
for spring-boot-maven-plugin and load changes in pom.xml

```
<build>
    <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
            </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was constantly getting the same error. I was getting error after plugin updates and eclipse update. I had spring boot and necessary plugins installed in eclipse. But the option to create a spring boot project was not appearing. I understood that it was not seeing the spring boot plugin. I also deleted eclipse. I reinstalled eclipse. I reinstalled the plugins. Problem solved. The simplest solution.
Solution -> Delete Eclipse ->(Optional Delete .m2,.p2,etc.) -> Install Eclipse -> Installing required plugins.(eclipse web developer tools, eclipse m2e,spring tools).

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was silly mistake I added dependency from Spring initializer where I mistook choosing gradle project instead of maven Project

Answer (score -1):

Delete the repository folder from "C:\Users\usename.m2" and create again or update maven project.

Comment: This seems to be more like a comment. Please do not post comments as answers.