# SpringBoot failing to run

Tags: java, spring, maven

I ran *maven* correctly but when I run the main class I get an error:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: SpringApplication cannot be resolved`

**Java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class CourseApiapp {

    public static void main(String []args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CourseApiapp.class, args);
    }
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: How do you run it?

Comment: Did you try maven clean install?

Comment: you mean clear .metadata folder ??

Comment: @LucianovanderVeekens normal running in main method but my error is clear above

Comment: "spring boot can't run". It's hard to run with only one boot. Sorry :)

Comment: I know it might be obvious, but is the SpringApplication class imported? Are you using any IDE, is it not suggesting any other problems?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Boot application can't resolve the org.springframework.boot package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33301073/spring-boot-application-cant-resolve-the-org-springframework-boot-package)

Answer (score 3):

I think that you have to point to a parent POM where dependencies are stored:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

Comment: <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

Answer (score 1):

1. Fix your pom as it is malformed. Here is a working one generated from start.spring.io

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
       <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

       <groupId>com.example</groupId>
       <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
       <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
       <packaging>jar</packaging>

       <name>demo</name>
       <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

       <parent>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
           <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
           <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
       </parent>

       <properties>
           <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
           <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
           <java.version>1.8</java.version>
       </properties>

       <dependencies>
           <dependency>
               <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
               <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
           </dependency>

           <dependency>
               <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
               <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
               <scope>test</scope>
           </dependency>
       </dependencies>

       <build>
           <plugins>
               <plugin>
                   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                   <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
               </plugin>
           </plugins>
       </build>


   </project>
   ```
2. Or If you are using IDE like intelliJ idea or Eclipse make sure to re
   import the project.
   Here is an answer how to refresh maven dependencies in eclipse

   [How to update maven repository in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2555845/how-to-update-maven-repository-in-eclipse)
3. Optionaly if you want to build from terminal.Try running the
   following command in console

   ```
       mvn spring-boot:run
   ```

Comment: sorry could you tell me where can i write that command and my IDE is STS  ?

Comment: @magedabdelkhalik And every ide has a re import or refresh procedure, which ide is you on?

Comment: please specify place

Comment: I thought the command to run spring-boot app was `mvn spring-boot:run`

Comment: im on STS IDE eclipse

Comment: @SukmaWardana thanks and updated, mixed it up with gradle :)

Comment: @magedabdelkhalik hi updated my answer see if it helps

Comment: @magedabdelkhalik That step is for building the project from command prompt, terminal, console. If you are not using one you can skip that step.