# while upgrading spring boots 1.4 from 1.5,

Tags: spring, spring-boot

showing error "Spring Boot application can't resolve the org.springframework.boot package" while upgrading from springboots 1.4 to 1.5.

how we will resolved

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33301073/spring-boot-application-cant-resolve-the-org-springframework-boot-package

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Boot application can't resolve the org.springframework.boot package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33301073/spring-boot-application-cant-resolve-the-org-springframework-boot-package)

Comment: Please show your complete pom?